# How can I do performance evaluation for aspect-based opinion mining?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have calculated some value for every aspect and identified its polarity using sentiwordnet.

For example, the movie is great. here movie is an aspect and I identified its value using some metric for example movie=1.5677 and polarity is positive. hereafter how can I identify the precision and recall?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have a discrete classifier, the precision would be how close your calculated scores are to the truth scores (something like sum squared error or sum absolute error would work). If you had a discrete classifier you could just calculate the number of correct classifications.

The recall would be the percentage of aspects that you were able to successfully extract. So for your example you extracted the only aspect, giving you a score of `1.0`. If the input was "The pizza and the movie were amazing" and you only extracted "movie", then your recall score would be `0.5`.

Normally you could combine your precision and recall scores into a [`F-Measure`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#F-measure), but, since you do not have a discrete classifier, you probably wouldn't be able to use the `F-Measure`.

Comment: how can we do discrete classifier for this?

Comment: You could just have 3 levels: negative, neutral, and positive

Comment: Depending on how your scorer works, you could just define ranges associated with each of those levels

Comment: I don't understand pls explain elaborately. I used negative, neutral, and positive  for polarity identification of sentiment analysis. but how can we do this for aspect.

Comment: I see, so your aspect has a score? What does this score mean/ where does it come from? If you have an `(aspect, sentiment)` pair then you can calculate recall as the percentage of aspects extracted. You would then have two precision scores: a) what percentage of aspects extracted are actually aspects and b) what percentage of sentiments are correct.

Comment: ok sir. but in the discrete classifier, how can we evaluate aspect?

Comment: An aspect is either an aspect or it is not. Just look at the proportion of extracted aspects which are actually aspects. Example input: "the movie was bad". Example output: `(movie, negative), (was, positive)`. Here we have one correct aspect (`movie`)  and one incorrect aspect (`was`) so your aspect precision is `0.5`

Answer (score 0):

for evaluate your models in NLP , we can use this as u know:

[Per and R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxmyb.jpg)

[F-score and Acuraccy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE9Io.jpg)

**1. evaluate Aspect Extraction model:**

**TP :**
    (true positive)
    Number of aspects that are correctly extracted
**FP :**
     (false positive)
      Number of aspects that are annotated, but the not extracted by the algorithm
**FN :**
     (false negative)
     Number of aspects that are not annotated, but extracted by the algorithm
**TN :**
      (true negative)
       Number of aspects that are not annotated and not extracted by the algorithm

---

**2. evaluate  Sentiment Classification model:**

**TP:**
     Number of sentiment polarity scores that are calculated correctly by the algorithm
**FP:**
     Number of sentiment polarity scores that are incorrectly calculated by the algorithm Irrelevant
**FN:**
     Number of aspects that does not have sentiment assigned, but calculated by the algorithm
**TN:**
     Number of aspects that does not have sentiment assigned and not calculated by the algorithm